# Python::Not reading data correctly from the file in S3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Requirement: To read data from S3 to pass into API

Error: `"error": {"code": "ModelStateInvalid", "message": "The request has exceeded the maximum number of validation errors.", "target": "HttpRequest"`

When I pass data directly in the code as below `document` , it works fine as below

```
def create_doc(self,client):
        self.n_docs = int(self.n_docs)
        document = {'addresses': {'SingleLocation': {'city': 'ABC', 
                                'country': 'US', 
                                'line1': 'Main', 
                                'postalCode': '00000', 
                                'region': 'CA'
                                    }
                                }, 
                            'commit': False, 
                            }
       response = client.cr_transc(document)            
       jsn = response.json()
```

But when tried having data in the file in the s3 and read it from s3 , it throws into error

```
def create_doc(self,client):
        self.n_docs = int(self.n_docs)
        document = data_from_s3()
        response = client.cr_transc(document)            
        jsn = response.json()

def data_from_s3(self):
     s3 = S3Hook()
     data = s3.read_key(bucket_name = self.bucket_name, key = self.data_key)
     return data
```

Below link is for read_key method in airflow

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.6/_modules/airflow/hooks/S3_hook.html#S3Hook:~:text=%5Bdocs%5D%20%20%20%20def-,read_key,-(self%2C

Comment: You are passing a dictionary into the `client.cr_transc` function, but is the data returned from the `S3Hook` a dict?

Answer (score 0):

Checking the [source code](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.6/_modules/airflow/hooks/S3_hook.html#S3Hook.read_key):

```py
def read_key(self, key, bucket_name=None):
    """
    Reads a key from S3

    :param key: S3 key that will point to the file
    :type key: str
    :param bucket_name: Name of the bucket in which the file is stored
    :type bucket_name: str
    """

    obj = self.get_key(key, bucket_name)
    return obj.get()['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')
```

This returns a `str`. You might need to use the `json` module to convert it:

```py
import json


def create_doc(self,client):
    self.n_docs = int(self.n_docs)
    document = json.loads(data_from_s3()) # <----- convert here
    response = client.cr_transc(document)            
    jsn = response.json()

def data_from_s3(self):
    s3 = S3Hook()
    data = s3.read_key(bucket_name = self.bucket_name, key = self.data_key)
    return data
```

Comment: I tried as you mentioned but got error as 
`json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property ***me enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)`

Comment: what does your document content look like? I've made an assumption that what's in your S3 file is similar to your non-s3 example

Comment: If it's non-json, you may need `ast.literal_eval`

Comment: Data looks like the first example i mentioned that it worked it same as it is